# send video through telegram python api

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I want to send a video through the API, there are functions to send text, images, audio and documents. Is there a function to send videos or should I use this function to do so?

bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=open('tests/test.zip', 'rb'))

Is there an easier/more correct way?

Comment: So implementing via bot.send_document works, however it returns a timeout error

Comment: pass `timeout=20` to the same method to override the default timeout, or even increase the number more

Answer (score 6):

The same as with documents

```
bot.send_video(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, video=open('output.mp4', 'rb'), supports_streaming=True)
```

`send_document` can sometimes send video as an actual document file, unplayable in TG

`send_video` will always send video, playable in TG and also, passing `supports_streaming=True` will make TG allow to stream before downloading.

More references about `send_video` and other `send_*` you can look up at
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/bot.py

To avoid timeout for sending use `updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', request_kwargs={'read_timeout': 1000, 'connect_timeout': 1000})`